# Vue: new project, app div has margin around it, how to remove blank space

Tags: html, css

I have this code in a brand new `Vue` project:

**App.vue**:

```
<template>

  <div id="app">
    <p>hey</p>
  </div>

</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {

  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  background-color: red;

  margin: 0px !important;
}
</style>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

As can be seen, there is white space on top of and to the left and to the right of the `app` `div`. How do I remove it, so that it looks like this:

[image]

**EDIT**:

Adding

```
body  {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

resulted in this:

[image]

Comment: `body { padding: 0; margin: 0 }` — you probably need to override the default browser styles.

Comment: @KirkBeard Added it, same output

Comment: @KirkBeard Adding the `margin` worked for horizontal space (see edit)

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this :**

```css
body {
  margin: 0px !important;
}
p {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
   <p>hey</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you shouldn't give elements an id of app since it is where Vue renders the whole application in the main index.html file and in general it is not recommended to have two elements with the same id.

Secondly, check where the margin/padding is coming from. Since you specified that giving the app a margin and padding of 0 with the important flag is not working, we could assume it's coming from either the body or any other higher level container. So make sure to give them the same no padding and margin properties. If the margin/padding is coming from the body then depending on what tool you used to build your app(Vue CLI, Vite, etc.) find the static index.html file and try to add an inline style such as the one below:

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the following to the CSS of my App.vue file.

```
#app {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

It selects the element with id "app" and makes the margin and padding 0.